# How to back-fill data column by date with a specified number of days in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset like below:

```
df1 = data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2019/12/18"), as.Date("2020/01/01"), 'days'))
df1 = df1 %>% mutate(holiday = case_when(date == '2019-12-25' ~'Christmas',
                                         date =='2020-01-01' ~ 'New Year'))

date        holiday
2019-12-18  NA          
2019-12-19  NA          
2019-12-20  NA          
2019-12-21  NA          
2019-12-22  NA          
2019-12-23  NA          
2019-12-24  NA          
2019-12-25  Christmas           
2019-12-26  NA          
2019-12-27  NA
2019-12-28  NA          
2019-12-29  NA          
2019-12-30  NA          
2019-12-31  NA          
2020-01-01  New Year
```

I need to back-fill holiday by 7 days. Note: there are 6 days between new year and Christmas. So what I need is like below:

```
date        holiday
2019-12-18  Christmas           
2019-12-19  Christmas           
2019-12-20  Christmas           
2019-12-21  Christmas           
2019-12-22  Christmas           
2019-12-23  Christmas           
2019-12-24  Christmas           
2019-12-25  Christmas           
2019-12-26  New Year            
2019-12-27  New Year
2019-12-28  New Year            
2019-12-29  New Year            
2019-12-30  New Year            
2019-12-31  New Year            
2020-01-01  New Year
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that?
I need a solution to be general. My real data has a long list of holidays. The solution should be applicable to other similar situations also., like back-fill two any number of days.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should add a more complex example, your expected output can be achieved with `df1 %>% fill(holiday, .direction = 'up')` but that is not what you want.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `fill` the `holiday` values with `direction = 'up'` and replace the values which are less than 2 days with `NA`. You can replace 2 with 7 for your actual case.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  tidyr::fill(holiday, .direction = 'up') %>%
  group_by(holiday) %>%
  mutate(new_holiday = replace(holiday, row_number() < n() - 2, NA))

#   date       holiday   new_holiday
#   <date>     <chr>     <chr>      
# 1 2019-12-18 Christmas NA         
# 2 2019-12-19 Christmas NA         
# 3 2019-12-20 Christmas NA         
# 4 2019-12-21 Christmas NA         
# 5 2019-12-22 Christmas NA         
# 6 2019-12-23 Christmas Christmas  
# 7 2019-12-24 Christmas Christmas  
# 8 2019-12-25 Christmas Christmas  
# 9 2019-12-26 New Year  NA         
#10 2019-12-27 New Year  NA         
#11 2019-12-28 New Year  NA         
#12 2019-12-29 New Year  NA         
#13 2019-12-30 New Year  New Year   
#14 2019-12-31 New Year  New Year   
#15 2020-01-01 New Year  New Year
```

Comment: Great! That's exactly what I need.